# Chrome Extension: Code inside chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener never gets executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to pass a variable from a content script to the popup.js using the sendMessage method.

This is the content script where I'm sending a message to the background script that contains the number of children of a DOM node:

```
let incomingChatsNumber = incomingChatsContainer.children().length;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ incomingChatsNumber: incomingChatsNumber });
```

Then the background.js listen to the message and send a messag itself with the same variable to the popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  let incomingChatsNumber = message.incomingChatsNumber;
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ incomingChatsNumber: incomingChatsNumber });
});
```

In the popup.js I have a button that will trigger some code if the "incomingChatsNumber" is more than 0 (the dom container has children):

```
  $("#js-toggleSorting").on("click", function () {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
      let incomingChatsNumber = message.incomingChatsNumber;
      if (incomingChatsNumber <= 0) {
        $(".message").html("<p>No Chats To Sort, You Joker</p>");
      } else {
        $(".message").html("<p>Sorting Chats</p>");
        //This code never gets executed
        if ($("#js-toggleSorting").attr("data-click-state") == 1) {
          $("#js-toggleSorting").attr("data-click-state", 0);
          $("#js-toggleSorting").html("SORT INCOMING CHATS");
          sortFunction(false);
        } else {
          $("#js-toggleSorting").attr("data-click-state", 1);
          $("#js-toggleSorting").html("STOP SORTING INCOMING CHATS");
          sortFunction(true);
        }
        save_button_state();
      }
    });
  });
```

The strange thing for me is that the popup.js gets the value right I can even console.log it, but as soon as I put more code on that if conditional the code never gets executed even when the condition is ok to go.

**UPDATE:**

After doing the modifications suggested by ehab I realized that the variable is "undefined" all the time because of the async nature of chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener:

Content Script:

```
  let incomingChatsNumber = incomingChatsContainer.children().length;
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ incomingChatsNumber: incomingChatsNumber });
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  let incomingChatsNumber = message.incomingChatsNumber;
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ incomingChatsNumber: incomingChatsNumber });
});
```

Popup.js (This is where I need to use the value of the incomingChatsNumber variable):

```
  let latestIncomingChatsNumber;

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    let incomingChatsNumber = message.incomingChatsNumber;
    latestIncomingChatsNumber = incomingChatsNumber;
    //This Works
    console.log(latestIncomingChatsNumber);
  });
  //This will give me an undefined value
  console.log(latestIncomingChatsNumber);
```

I get that my problem is related to the fact that the chrome.* APIs are asynchronous so The chrome.runtime... and the console.log(...) will be executed at the same time, hence the error. So how to use the latestIncomingChatsNumber variable inside an on click event then ? Do I have to to save "latestIncomingChatsNumber" to the local storage inside the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener first ?

Comment: Assuming you know that the popup runs every time it's shown and stopped when hidden, the only problem I see in the code is that you add a new listener on every click, which is wrong.

Comment: Is there any way I can use the variable passed from the background as a global on the popup.js ? I'm just doing that on the click event since I don't know how to do that. Thanks @wOxxOm

Answer (score 1):

You should not put an event listener inside another event handler, this is an extremely bad practice even if it do what you think it should be doing, this will cause memory leaks for you down the road, and makes the code hard to read and semantically incorrect.

It seems based on looking at your code the problem is that the handler for the message gets called multiple times because of previous event listeners added in the click evet

```
 let latestIncomingChatsNumber
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
      let incomingChatsNumber = message.incomingChatsNumber;
      // save this into the application state, i will use a parent scope variable you could use something else 
       latestIncomingChatsNumber = incomingChatsNumber
    });
    
 $("#js-toggleSorting").on("click", function () {
      if (latestIncomingChatsNumber <= 0) {
        $(".message").html("<p>No Chats To Sort, You Joker</p>");
      } else {
        $(".message").html("<p>Sorting Chats</p>");
        //This code never gets executed
        if ($("#js-toggleSorting").attr("data-click-state") == 1) {
          $("#js-toggleSorting").attr("data-click-state", 0);
          $("#js-toggleSorting").html("SORT INCOMING CHATS");
          sortFunction(false);
        } else {
          $("#js-toggleSorting").attr("data-click-state", 1);
          $("#js-toggleSorting").html("STOP SORTING INCOMING CHATS");
          sortFunction(true);
        }
        save_button_state(); // i believe this function saves the attributes to the dom elements
      }
  });
```

if `save_button_state` does a good job the code i shared should work

Comment: That's exactly what I needed @ehab. I was so concentrated on making the message passing work correctly that I forgot how to avoid those multiple calls. Many thanks !

Comment: sorry to re-open the question again but after everything was working find suddenly I'm starting to get an "undefined" when trying to access the "latestIncomingChatNumber" from the popup.js. Just wondering if this has anything to do with the need of saving the state of that variable on the local storage, any idea ? I have updated my question.